# Find formula/function for data points

Tags: regression, data-analysis

I'm trying to find a function to a problem.

I have data points of

**Volume (in ml)** - **Sugar Content(in Grams)** - **ABV(alcohol by Volume)**

Like:

```
1500    500 16.375
1500    400 13.100
1500    300 9.825
1500    200 6.550
1500    100 3.275
1500    50  1.375
1500    0   0.000
1600    100 2.751
1400    100 3.144
1200    100 3.668
1000    100 4.585
800     100 5.764
600     100 7.860
400     100 12.052
200     100 24.366
```

I'm using [this](http://gotmead.com/blog/the-mead-calculator/) site to get the values, so I have as many as I need.

What I'm trying to find is the relationship of Volume to ABV in a fixed amount of Sugar.

I managed to find the relationship from Sugar to ABV in a fixed amount of Volume, which is 0.03537% for every Gram of sugar;

I thought that the Volume-ABV was going to be as easy, but I'm stuck. I tried [this website](http://www.xuru.org/rt/TOC.asp)  for regression from data, but It didn't spit out any good formula.

Do anyone have a clue what can I do to get this formula right?

Answer (score 1):

If we look at the data for $100$ grams of sugar, that is to say
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{Volume} & \text {ABV} \\
 1600 & 2.751 \\
 1500 & 3.275 \\
 1400 & 3.144 \\
 1200 & 3.668 \\
 1000 & 4.585 \\
 800 & 5.764 \\
 600 & 7.860 \\
 400 & 12.052 \\
 200 & 24.366
\end{array}
\right)$$
it seems that a model such as $$\text{ABV}=\frac a {V^b}$$ could do a quite good job. You can linearize the model $$\log(\text{ABV})=c+d\log(V)$$ to get estimates of the parameters (standard linear regression) and then use nonlinear regression using as estimates $a=e^c$ anb $b=-d$.

This would give 
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & 5874. & 282 & \{5185,6563\} \\
 b & 1.0349 & 0.0084 & \{1.0555,1.0143\} \\
\end{array}$$

**Edit**

All the above has been done using basic linear and nonlinear regression methods. If you want to combine both effects (what I did not do because a lack of data points, what I should do is to repeat the same process for different amounts of sugar and look how vary the parameters.

You could even simplify the problem assuming (if confirmed) that $b \approx 1$. Taking into your observation, may be model could just be $$\text{ABV}=\frac {\alpha \times \text{sugar}} {V}$$ Using the whole set of data points given in the post, it seems that $\alpha\approx 48.5$ leads to something acceptable.

This would give using the whole set of data points
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \text{Volume} & \text {Sugar} & \text {ABV}& \text {predicted}\\
 1500 & 500 & 16.375 & 16.173 \\
 1500 & 400 & 13.1  & 12.938 \\
 1500 & 300 & 9.825 & 9.704\\
 1500 & 200 & 6.55 & 6.469\\
 1500 & 100 & 3.275 & 3.235 \\
 1500 & 50 & 1.375 & 1.617\\
 1500 & 0 & 0. & 0.\\
 1600 & 100 & 2.751 & 3.032\\
 1400 & 100 & 3.144 & 3.466\\
 1200 & 100 & 3.668 & 4.043\\
 1000 & 100 & 4.585 & 4.852\\
 800 & 100 & 5.764 & 6.065\\
 600 & 100 & 7.86 & 8.087\\
 400 & 100 & 12.052 & 12.130\\
 200 & 100 & 24.366 & 24.260
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Could you explain how you came to those values for **a** and **b**? It works great but I can't manage to join both formulas, what I'm trying to do is generalize a formula that takes both **Vol* and **Sugar Cont**

Comment: @f.rodrigues. See my edit. All of that can be done using Excel.